# Disable click button event c#

Tags: c#, events, button

I program in Visual Studio 2013 C#.
I want to have a functionality to disable for short time a button.
I tried `button.Enabled=false`,  but I see that when I click it during it is disabled then the click action starts right after I get that button enabled in other place of the program.

How to clear that event or block them when button is disabled?

Best regards,
Krzysztof

Comment: are you using WinForms or WPF?

Comment: Normally, the event will not be triggered after button is being enabled. Thus, can show us how you enable the button?

Answer (score 10):

for disable button click.

```
button1.Click -= button1_Click; // here button1_Click is your event name
```

for enable button click.

```
button1.Click += button1_Click; // here button1_Click is your event name
```

Comment: Are you sure it is for C# Web Forms? It seems like it is for Windows Forms...

Answer (score 6):

This is the extremely simple way that I found on the internet and it works.

1. Disable the button(s)
2. Run whatever is needed to be performed on the procedure
3. Run this command `Application.DoEvent();`. This command enqueues all the click events (as many as the user clicked) and ignore/dispose them
4. Enable the button(s) at the end

Good Luck

Answer (score 3):

Can't you just check for button's state before executing commands in the method?
For example:

```
void Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!(sender as Button).Enabled)
        return;

    //other statements
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
YourButton.Attributes.Add("onClick", "");
```

To remove its onClick altogether.

and then

```
 YourButton.Attributes.Add("onClick", "YourButton_Click");
```

To add it again.

But your program shouldn't execute the Click when you say it does. It's likely there's something wrong in your code's logic.

Comment: button.attributes.add("disabled", "true");

Comment: @AbdulKhaliq this changes the style of the btn https://codepen.io/teneke/pen/poYgvzV

Answer (score 0):

Look at this code below, after click button2, button 1 is disabled. while button 1 is disabled, click button 1. After button 1 enable automatically after 5 seconds textBox1 update to "Update".

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = "Update";
    }


    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button1.Enabled = false;

        Thread.Sleep(5000);

        button1.Enabled = true;

    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = "";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

btn.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;

You can try this.

Comment: btnSearch.Attributes.Add("disabled", "true");