# Old form still display winforms c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I implement a form for handle excel file when click button "Start".
Event click Start button:

```
private void btnImport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            showFormSelectLanguage();
            if (CheckSheetFile() == true) {
                using (WaitingForm frm = new WaitingForm(handleExcel))
                {
                    frm.ShowDialog(this);
                }
                var dialogMessage = new DialogMessage();
                dialogMessage.ShowDialog(this);
            } else
            {
                ShowDialogNotFoundSheet();
            }
        }
```

showFormSelectLanguage method display dialog for select language:

```
private void showFormSelectLanguage()
        {
            var formSelectLanguage = new FormSelectLanguage();
            formSelectLanguage.ShowDialog(this);
        }
```

ShowDialogNotFoundSheet function for check sheet excel exist:

```
private void ShowDialogNotFoundSheet()
        {
            var dialogNotFoundSheet = new DialogNotFoundSheet();
            dialogNotFoundSheet.setTextContent("Not found sheet");
            dialogNotFoundSheet.ShowDialog(this);
        }
```

Event click confirm select language button at Select language form:

```
private void btnConfirmLanguage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //close dialog
            this.Close();
        }
```

Event click Close button for close DialogNotFoundSheet form:

```
private void btnCloseDialogNotFoundSheet_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }
```

CheckSheetFile method:

```
private bool CheckSheetFile()
        {
            var isCorrectFile = false;
            try
            {
                xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(txtFilePath.Text, System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read);
                var xlWorkBook1 = xlWorkBook.Sheets["SheetName"];
                isCorrectFile = true;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return false;
            }
            return isCorrectFile;
        }
```

**Issue:**
When I click Close button at DialogNotFoundSheet form. Then FormSelectLanguage from still display. It repeats. How can resolve it?
Expected 2 forms can close
Thanks!

Update:
All References btnImport_Click:
[image: References btnImport_Click]

UI:
[image: FormSelectLanguage]
[image: DialogNotFoundSheet]

Comment: Why this question has 2 upvotes and 0 answers?

Comment: How could you show a `DialogNotFoundSheet` dialog if `FormSelectLanguage` dialog hadn't been closed? My guess is you may have `new FormSelectLanguage()` in the `CheckSheetFile` method.

Comment: I tried init FormSelectLanguage in the CheckSheetFile method, It still error same. @shingo

Comment: I mean you'll have this problem if you create a new `FormSelectLanguage` inside `CheckSheetFile`. You'd better add this method in your question.

Comment: At first, I don't create new FormSelectLanguage inside CheckSheetFile
I update CheckSheetFile method in question for you.

Comment: _"It repeats"_ Does it repeat infinitely or not?

Comment: Yep, it repeat infinitely

Comment: https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/video/9483702?key=2ebf73f520d2de5f46ec87873ec0dbca
Video here

Comment: Right click on `btnImport_Click` -> `Find All References`, see what you get.

Comment: @shingo wow. I had call btnImport_Click for handle disable onClick like there: [disable click event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34284232/disable-click-button-event-c-sharp). I try comment code then issue not happen. Can you explant it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't exactly know what you did with `btnImport_Click`, but if your purpose is to disable the function of a button at a time and to enable it at another time, actually you don't have to register or unregister the click event, you can simply set button's `Enabled` propety.

```
//btnImport.Click += btnImport_Click;
btnImport.Enabled = true;

//btnImport.Click -= btnImport_Click;
btnImport.Enabled = false;
```

---

My guess of the reason of this loop is that you have called `+= btnImport_Click` many times, but `-= btnImport_Click` is never (or less) run.

For instance if you do:

```
btnImport.Click += btnImport_Click;
btnImport.Click += btnImport_Click;
```

Each time `btnImport` is clicked, `btnImport_Click` will get invoked twice.

Comment: Thank bro. But when I set enable = false then Mouse_Move event not working.
For simple, I don't using Mouse_Move event (for handle cursor display type) and remove code: 
`btnImport.Click += btnImport_Click;
btnImport.Click += btnImport_Click;`

Comment: MouseMove on a button? OK, you can keep registering the click event, just remember that when the form is loaded, `btnImport_Click` is already listened once, and you must ensure that you call `+= btnImport_Click` as many times as call `-= btnImport_Click`.

Comment: Ok bro. This is root cause form repeats. Thank you! 
I resolved it. :D